# How to split the content of one column into two columns of csv in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

I got an object of CSV, the content is like:

```
full_name  | phone_number  |
Mike Smith | (123)-456-7890|
Tony Davis | (213)-564-7890|
```

And I would like to split the column of 'full_name' into two columns, which represents 'first_name' and 'last_name':

```
first_name | last_name | phone_number  |
Mike       | Smith     | (123)-456-7890|
Tony       | Davis     | (213)-564-7890|
```

I didn't find a command to do it, how can I split it? Thank you very much!

The code for this part is:

```
def to_csv(options = {})
  CSV.generate(options) do |csv|
    columns = %w[ full_name phone_number ]

    csv << columns
    each do |books|
      csv << columns.map { |column| books.public_send(column) }
                    .map { |column| ActionController::Base.helpers.strip_tags(column.to_s) }
    end
  end
end
```

And this method is called by:

```
send_data(books.to_csv(col_sep: ','),filename: 'booksAuthorsInfo.csv',type: 'application/csv')
```

The class type of 'books' is ActiveRecord_AssociationRelation, and I don't know how to split that full_name column into two columns, it looks like the String.split is not helpful.

Comment: @SimpleLime Hi thank you for replying. I get an object from ActiveRecord_AssociationRelation object first, and then I put the data of this object into a CSV object. I don't know if it's what you want to know, please let me know if you need more information, thank you so much!!!

Comment: What code have you written so far / what progress have you made? The docs show how to write a csv file here: https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.1/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html, and how to do string manipulation here: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-split

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your question is poorly asked. Please read "[ask]" and its linked pages. We need to know what attempt you made to solve this problem. As is, it appears you didn't try and want us to write code for you, which is off-topic. I'll give you a hint that String's `split` command and the CSV class will be helpful.

Comment: @avimoondra Hi, I just added the code I have written, could you look at it? I want to split the full_name field into two fields which represents first_name and last_name, but I'm a beginner of ruby and don't know how to do it. Since the data type is not a string, I think I can't use split. Thanks for the link you provided, but I still don't find command from that link to split the certain column.

Comment: It's still not clear what you're trying to do. Show us *exactly* how you gather your "object of CSV". What is the data that creates it. Splitting a space delimited string is very trivial. CSV is a class that provides conversion of hashes or arrays to a CSV file; CSV doesn't contain anything, so an "object of CSV" means little, except it's what you use to access CSV methods.

Answer (score 0):

So far the question doesn't make enough sense so I expect it'll be closed eventually. Here's some information about how to split the fields so that, *maybe*, we can get to the real root of the problem.

Meditate on this:

```
ary = <<EOT
full_name  | phone_number  |
Mike Smith | (123)-456-7890|
Tony Davis | (213)-564-7890|
EOT

PIPE_DELIMITER = /\s*\|\s*/

munged_data = ary.lines[1..-1].map { |l|
  full_name, phone_number = l.split(PIPE_DELIMITER)  # => ["Mike Smith", "(123)-456-7890"], ["Tony Davis", "(213)-564-7890"]
  first_name, last_name = full_name.split # => ["Mike", "Smith"],                ["Tony", "Davis"]
  [first_name, last_name, phone_number]
}
# => [["Mike", "Smith", "(123)-456-7890"], ["Tony", "Davis", "(213)-564-7890"]]
```

At this point it's possible to generate some usable CSV data:

```
require 'csv'
CSV.open("/dev/stdout", "wb") do |csv|
  csv << %w[first_name last_name phone_number]
  munged_data.each do |row|
    csv << row
  end
end
```

Which results in:

```
# >> first_name,last_name,phone_number
# >> Mike,Smith,(123)-456-7890
# >> Tony,Davis,(213)-564-7890
```

Note the use of a regular expression as a parameter to `split`; This tells `split` to clean up the resulting output a bit by only splitting on zero-or-more whitespace delimited by `|`:

```
PIPE_DELIMITER = /\s*\|\s*/

full_name, phone_number = l.split('|')             # => ["Mike Smith ", " (123)-456-7890", "\n"], ["Tony Davis ", " (213)-564-7890", "\n"]
full_name, phone_number = l.split(PIPE_DELIMITER)  # => ["Mike Smith", "(123)-456-7890"],         ["Tony Davis", "(213)-564-7890"]
```

At that point it is easy to split the names:

```
first_name, last_name = full_name.split # => ["Mike", "Smith"],                        ["Tony", "Davis"]
```